# Calling Yahoo API through OAuth

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, yahoo, yahoo-api

Spending my whole day on yahoo docs and here and there finally I am asking it here having failed in all attempts.I am implementing login with yahoo on my site using yahoo oauth. After a user login I need to get his profile.
I have successfully retrieved access token and completed the authorization flow as mentioned here:-
[Yahoo OAuth authorization flow](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html)

After having the access token I need to retrieve the user profile by just making a simple Yahoo API call as mentioned [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-make-request.html)

But I not able to the same. Sometimes it gives me token rejected sometimes signature invalid,timestamp rejected e.t.c. I have seen similar type of question on Yahoo Forums but there are no replies to that people(I wonder what they did). 
I would be really thankful if someone can describe this step completely, very clearly(signatures,methods,timestamp e.t.c) as it will be useful for users having similar problems. I am using JAVA language.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Are you doing this with javascript or on the server side?

Comment: I am using server side